# Comparing strings and arrays c#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string

How would i go about making a function that would return `true` if a string contains any element of an array?

Something like this:

```
string str = "hi how are you";
string[] words = {"hi", "hey", "hello"};
```

would return `true`.

Comment: `foreach` + `String.IndexOf`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var array = new[] {"quick", "brown", "fox"};
var myString = "I love foxes.";
if (array.Any(s => myStr.IndexOf(s) >= 0)) {
    // One of the elements is there
}
```

This approach does *not* require that the element be a full word (i.e. the above fragment would return `true`, even though the word `"fox"` is not present there as a single word).

Comment: Or if you don't mind losing a mild amount of efficiency for more readability: `if (array.Any(s => myStr.Contains(s)) {` will do as well, I believe.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i was looking for! Thanks also for fixing my bad formatting Mr_Green :) Also is it easy to change it so that it is case insensitive?

Comment: @user1852287 Yes - use `myStr.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` to make it case-insensitive.

Comment: Smaller yet: `bool b = words.Any(str.Contains);`

Answer (score 0):

You can split a string and use `Enumerable.Intersect`. It will be much more efficient for long strings than `Any` + `IndexOf`:

```
var any = words.Intersect(str.Split()).Any();
```

Comment: @user18522877 This assumes you're looking for entire words rather than substrings, so in an example like dasblinkenlight's it will return `false` - that might be what you're looking for, but if it is then you should probably change your question.

Answer (score 0):

No need of looping,here is a faster method :

```
   string [] arr = {"One","Two","Three"};
   var target = "One";
   var results = Array.FindAll(arr, s => s.Equals(target));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check whether a string contains in other string (I dont know about performance)

```
foreach(string strLine in words)
 {
    if(strLine.Contains(str)) //or str.Contains(strLine)
    {
      return true;
    }
 }
 //return false;
```